# Is it possible to call a dbt doc function within another dbt doc function?

Tags: jinja2, dbt

DBT's/jinja's [doc function](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/doc) allows usage of a doc block, defined in a markdown file. I want to be able to reference a doc block inside another doc block. Is this possible to do?

**Desired:**

```
{% docs description_1 %}
This is the 1st description.
{% enddocs %}

{% docs description_2 %}
This is the 2nd description.

Also: {{ doc("description_1") }}

{% enddocs %}
```